# How to setup a public github unity repo with paid assets?

Tags: unity, licensing, open-source, git

From what I gathered (like in [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/question-are-you-allowed-to-post-you-project-on-github-open-source.475346/) or [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/135795/am-i-allowed-to-push-my-unity-based-games-source-code-to-github)) I am allowed to push my own game code on github and choose a license, as long as I avoid putting assets I do not own. I want to make it public to be able to show it (to potential employers for instance) [but I cannot make it open source](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/173803/how-can-i-open-source-my-unity-project-when-i-use-third-party-assets) as I plan to use paid assets (like [DoozyUI](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/doozyui-complete-ui-management-system-138361)).

I can avoid pushing  the asset itself on the repo (with .gitignore for instance). **Should I prevent gameobjects created with this package to be pushed as well ?** That would make the game unusable, even with the rights to use the package...

Once that is settled, **Is it ok to push it to github without license ?**

Specifically, I do not know if objects generated by a paid asset are still considered that asset or not...

**Edit:** I asked the question directly to DoozyUI support, which quickly responded :

> You can upload your project, without the Doozy folder. Thus excluding our source code from being shared. Also, unsert a disclaimer letting anyone know that DoozyUI is required to be installed (before getting your files) for the project to work.
>   **You can share any GameObject (or prefabs) you create**, but they will not work if DoozyUI is not installed due to missing references (scripts). Once Doozy is installed, they will work as expected. Thus anyone who has the system will be able to see/use your project.

Comment: Is there still a point to put it on github ? Would people be allowed to grab it and test it in a personal context ?

Comment: Do you want potential employers to be able to play your game, or also look at the code? Have you thought of putting a (binary) build of your game somewhere that people can download and play, but also providing only the code available on github? So that you don't expect people to compile your github project, but employers can also see what state the code is in.

Comment: I think I'll make the compiled game available anyway yes. Maybe as a zip on github or hosted somewhere else. For the project itself, I'm not convinced that any employer would go through the process of downloading it (and necessary packages, assuming the have them) to inspect or compile it in unity. I'ts mainly to allow browsing the code online.

Comment: I would advice to do exactly that. This way you don't have to upload your assets on github. Also its worth mentioning that websites like github are meant for source code, so maybe it wouldn't be the best idea to upload a binary there. You can always use a hosting website, or maybe a game website, like Itch.io ?

Comment: I had not considered something like Itch.io for an unfinished product, but it's a good idea ! thanks

Comment: This might have changed, but some time back you could use Itch.io for betas, or to have a private project and share it to others with a link. So it can definitely be used for unfinished projects :)

Answer (score 3):

i already answered this question here:
[How can I open source my Unity project when I use third party assets?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/173803/how-can-i-open-source-my-unity-project-when-i-use-third-party-assets/175166#175166)

you cant publish your project except you exclude those paid assets out of your project.

Comment: So that means I can publish it without license and excluding paid assets ?

Comment: @Pierre that means you cant do that unlese you exclude those paid assets from your project and tell your users to import those assets if they want to make your project work

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I get what you are saying, but it does not answer the issue of generated game objects, are they considered "my code" ?

Comment: can you tell what are those paid assets. any paid asset that makes your prject work is assumed that you cant publish

Comment: I do not know if objects generated by a paid asset are still considered that asset or not. That's my question.

Comment: @virtouso If you believe this question is already covered by another question, then you should vote to close it as a duplicate.

Comment: @Pikalek alright.